# Suggestions for changing the function in the map expression

Tags: python, function, numpy

I am wondering if there is a more succinct method for doing the following:

When `h`, `t`, `r` are numpy arrays, I want to do the following:

```
hL, tL, rL = map(lambda m: len(set(m)), [h, t, r])
```

which computes the number of non-repeated items in the individual arrays. However, the lambda expression sticks out like a sore thumb. If the non-repeated thing weren't a problem, I would have written:

```
hL, tL, rL = map(len, [h, t, r])
```

Which is so much cooler. We have dispensed of the lambda expression in its entirety. Having dabbled in Haskell for a couple of months, I am really beginning to believe that Python should be able to provide a chaining operator like `.` in Haskell so that the first expression can be simply reduced to the following:

```
hL, tL, rL = map(len . set, [h, t, r])
```

Which is so much better!!

I saw something that uses the `reduce` method for doing this, but that is simply more ugly than the previous method. I wonder if anyone has something that they know about that can solve the problem? I am aware that there are problems with non-strict evaluation that *may* make programs unstable, but when we are working on simple things like this, that should not be a concern?

Answer (score 4):

To compute the number of unique elements in a numpy array, you can use `unique(x).size` or `len(unique(x))` (see [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)).  If you really want to make the calculation of the three lengths a "one-liner", you could write:

```
hL, tL, rL = [len(unique(x)) for x in h, t, r]
```

In case it matters: for moderate to large arrays, `unique(x)` can be a lot faster than `set(x)`, but for small arrays, `set(x)` is faster.  (I haven't explored the performance over a wide range of array sizes and data types, so I'll leave "large" and "small" undefined.  Test it yourself--but only if this code is a performance bottleneck.)

Answer (score 3):

Python does not provide composition operator.

How about using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)?

```
>>> h = [1,2,3]
>>> t = [1,1,1,1]
>>> r = [1,2,2,1]
>>> hL, tL, rL = [len(set(m)) for m in h, t, r]
>>> hL, tL, rL
(3, 1, 2)
```

Comment: actually that does look better. Thanks!